# Iterating through geodatabase with multiple feature datasets using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I am trying to create a Python script that batch projects every shapefile in a geodatabase to a temporary geodatabase that I created. I realized that this script that I created does not iterate through the multiple feature datasets of the geodatabase.

[image]

The code that I created only projects the file "breaklines". I need to also iterate through "Contours" and "Hydro". I know that I need to create a double loop but I am not sure how to do it. Here is the code that I started below

```
import glob, os, shutil, time, arcpy

path = r"C:\...\SARA_New_Contours.gdb"
temp = r"C:\...\Temp.gdb"


string1 = "\\metersproj-"


arcpy.env.workspace = path
out_coor_system = arcpy.SpatialReference("C:\...\NAD 1983 (2011) StatePlane Texas S Central FIPS 4204 (Meters).prj")

for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    prefix = string1 + fc
    out_dataset = temp + "\\" + prefix
    arcpy.Project_management (fc, out_dataset, out_coor_system)
```

**A side question: How would I just loop through one dataset, for example: just the feature dataset called "Contours"?**

Comment: Those aren't "folders" -- they're Feature Datasets, which are *displayed* in the UI as folders. Look at the ListDatasets documentation.

Comment: Thank you! I updated the question to make more sense. Still having trouble figuring it out. I know its an easy fix, taking a long to time to read and figure it out. What is the one line of code that I am missing?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat the feature dataset as a sub-folder of the file geodatabase. Set `path = r"C:\...\SARA_New_Contours.gdb\Contours"`, and your `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()` will only return the contents of Contours.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Bjorn's answer.

You can iterate through all the feature datasets within a file geodatabase (or SDE) with the following:

```
fcList = []
for fds in arcpy.ListDatasets('', 'feature'):
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('','',fds):
        fcList.append(fc)
```

This will attach all the feature classes to a list which you can then work with.